# Javascript Convert function to arrow function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angualr and have the following typescript function:

```
public watchLocationPath() {
    this.$scope.$watch(() =>
        this.$location.path(), function(value) {this.console.log(value);
    });
}
```

The `this` object is `undefined`, because it is out of scope. To fix this, I can change the existing `function(value)` to rather use arrow notation (then the `this` object will be in scope).

However, when I convert it to the following,

```
    this.$scope.$watch(() =>
        this.$location.path(), (value) => {this.console.log(value);
    });
```

I get errors at compile time.

- TSLint: Parentheses are prohibited around the parameter in this single parameter arrow function (arrow-parens)
- Unresolved variable `console`

Any advise welcome.

Comment: First error: Remove parentheses around `value`. Second error: You don't need `this.console` but just `console`.

Comment: why do you have a `this.console.log` instead of `console.log`?

Comment: Or configure the `arrow-parens` rule appropriately if you prefer this style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need no curly brackets, and no `this` for the console.

```
this.$scope.$watch(
    () => this.$location.path(),
    value => console.log(value)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I need to wait 10 min before I can mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to wrap `location.path` into another function. Also you could access `console` without `this.`

```
// no need to wrap single parameter like `(value)` for your tsLint config.
this.$scope.$watch(this.$location.path, value =>{
   //this from parent

})
```